# How do I get first column and a few rows in R using indexing?

Tags: r, database, dataframe, computer-science, rdata

I used the head function with the head `dataset[,head("column")]`. But this displays all the rows in column 1 not just few.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You could do `head(dataset)[,1]` to see the first few values of the first column.

Comment: You can also easily isolate the rows/columns you want to see.  e.g. `dataset[1:3, c(2,5,6)]` will print to console columns 2, 5, 6 of rows 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Also, `head("column")` results in `"column"`. So what you were really doing was `dataset[, "column"]` which returns a vector of `column`